# io-ts conditional / optional types

Tags: typescript, bash

I'm working on writing a codec to validate our environment variables.

We have some dependencies between the variables however, that some of them only make sense if other ones are present.

For example, if we have the RUN_DB_SEEDER=true, then I would want to enforce some additional env vars to configure the seeder.

However, if you are not going to run the seeder, you should not have to pass in those options.

So I'd like my codec to consider these types valid:

```bash
RUN_DB_SEEDER=true
DB_SEED_SIZE=100
```

```bash
RUN_DB_SEEDER=false
```

But NOT allow this

```bash
RUN_DB_SEEDER=true
```

since if you flag that you want to seed the db, then you must supply the parameters for that.

I realise this could be done with a giant, custom codec, but I want to leverage composition of codecs so I can have a config object that looks like this:

```
export const Config = t.type({
  RUN_DB_SEEDER=t.string,
  DB_SEED_SIZE=t.string,
  // ...
  PORT_NUMBER=t.string
});
```

so I can leverage simple codecs for most of the fields.  This makes it easy to add new env vars as the project progresses.

I also can see that it would be possible to do this by creating a more complex env var, something like this:

```bash
SEED_CONFIG={ run: true, seedSize: 100}
```

but I don't like having massive objects for the env var, I'd rather split it into multiple environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit verbose, but I have come up with one potential solution.

I made two codecs, one that asserts a boolean is true, and the other that a boolean is false.

Then I was able to make this test:

```
it(`tests union`, () => {
  const NoSeedConfig = t.type({
    RUN_DB_SEEDER: CBooleanIsFalse,
  });
  const SeedConfig = t.type({
    RUN_DB_SEEDER: CBooleanIsTrue,
    DB_SEED_SIZE: t.number,
  });

  const SeedCodec = t.union([SeedConfig, NoSeedConfig]);
  const noSeeding = {
    RUN_DB_SEEDER: false,
  };
  const someSeeding = {
    RUN_DB_SEEDER: true,
    SEED_VALUE: 150,
  };
  const invalidSeeding = {
    RUN_DB_SEEDER: true,
  };

  expect(E.isRight(SeedCodec.decode(noSeeding))).toEqual(true);
  expect(E.isRight(SeedCodec.decode(someSeeding))).toEqual(true);
  expect(E.isRight(SeedCodec.decode(invalidSeeding))).toEqual(false);
});
```

So basically, the two valid types are either:

```
{
  RUN_DB_SEEDER: false,
}
```

Or

```
{
  RUN_DB_SEEDER: true,
  DB_SEED_SIZE: number,
}
```

and so the union is equivalent to an OR condition, and so it has to match one or the other of those types

Comment: ok so that does decode correctly, but the run-time type is only the boolean value, cannot access the other ones

Comment: figured it out, you can run the type-guard to access the values
```ts
if (Seed.config.is(config)) {
  config.DB_SEED_SIZE // will be on the type
}
```

Comment: ok found it in the docs - https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/index.md#mixing-required-and-optional-props